# How to show that if $\sum a_n^{3/2}$ is bounded implies $\sum a_n/n$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> How to show that if $\sum a_n^{3/2}$ is bounded implies  $\sum a_n/n$ is bounded?

Actually I do not able to compare both series .SO could not able to solve above problem?

What should be strategy to solve this problem?

ANy Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Hölder's inequality (assuming that $a_n$ is positive).

Comment: Is it mean that $\sum |a_n/n|<\sum |a_n^{3/2}||\sum 1/n^3|^{1/3 }$ which is bounded

Comment: You lost a power of $\frac{2}{3}$ for the first sum, but otherwise yes.

Comment: yes sorry I forget to write